# zend retriving tag list

Tags: sql, zend-framework, join, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have some problem with zend. Here it is. I'm going to make some kind of articles db, which containt some info. Every article is marked with 1 or more tags (like WordPress).

I have a controller (let it be index) and action (also index).
All I need is to get articles and tags, associated with it, when user goes to site/index/index.

I have 3 tables:

```
articles(idarticles, title..)
tags(idtags, title)
tagList(idarticles, idtags).
```

How can I read tags, associated with article?

Comment: Seems to be more a SQL-Question. I retagged your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Zend's MVC doesn't actually include a model, however, the [quickstart guide outlines creating a model](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html).

The simplest way (not necessarily the best way), is to setup the connection in your `application.ini`, or setup the adapter like this (see the [`Zend_Db_Adapter`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html) docs):

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
  'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
  'username' => 'webuser',
  'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
  'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

Then use SQL to select your data.

```
//all articles
$articles = $db->query('SELECT * FROM articles');
//a article's tags
$tags = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tagList JOIN tags ON 
        (tagList.idtag = tags.idtags) WHERE idarticles = ?', $idarticles);
```

This is also taged for [`Zend_Db_Table`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html), to use that to access the data, first setup a default adapter (or again, use `application.ini`):

```
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($dbAdapter);
```

Then get objects for you tables like this:

```
$ariclesTable = new Zend_Db_Table('articles');
```

To get all the articles:

```
$articles = $articlesTable->fetchAll();
```

To get an article's tags (little more complex here, using a `Zend_Db_Table_Select` as recommended):

```
$select = $tagsTable->select();
//3rd argument must be empty array, so no joined columns are selected
$select->join('tagList', 'tagList.idtag = tags.idtags', array()); 
$select->where('tagList.idarticles = ?', $idarticles);
$tags = tagsTable->fetchAll($select);
```

Comment: I'm not sure the `getSelect` method exists in table, maybe you where meaning `select`.

Comment: @Juan Indeed I was, SO needs some kind of auto complete. Fixed now.